# CRIME and BREACH attacks, HTTP/2 and HTTP/3

Tags: breach, crime, http2

I have been reading on CRIME and BREACH attacks and I want to learn better how to protect against them.

From what I understood, those attacks require TLS encryption over HTTP compression and HTTP content reflecting an user input.

HTTP/2 uses HPACK and HTTP/3 uses QPACK header compressions, which are secure against CRIME and BREACH. If my secret data is only inside headers, does that mean that I can safely use compression on the whole request / response, with HTTP/2 or HTTP/3?

Answer (score 1):

A [compression side channel attack](https://www.sjoerdlangkemper.nl/2016/08/23/compression-side-channel-attacks/) is possible when some content contains both a secret and some user input and is then compressed. The assumption is that the attacker can observe the size of the compressed content, but not the content itself (because it is encrypted). Compression is more effective if the user input is more similar to the secret, so if the size decreases the attacker knows he is on the right track.

BREACH targets compression of the request content. By sending many requests through a CSRF-like setup, and observing the size, a secret value in the request content (typically the CSRF token) can be guessed approx. one bit at a time.

HPACK and QPACK have some mitigations against this, but do not offer total protection. Headers are not compressed at character-level, but headers with the same value are still compressed. This makes it impossible to guess character by character, so this makes the attack much harder.

From [RFC 9204](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9204.html#name-applicability-to-qpack-and-):

> QPACK mitigates, but does not completely prevent, attacks modeled on CRIME by forcing a guess to match an entire field line rather than individual characters. An attacker can only learn whether a guess is correct or not, so the attacker is reduced to a brute-force guess for the field values associated with a given field name.

Comment: So that means, for example, that sending a JWT token via header compressed with HPACK or QPACK is a bad idea? They are safer than other compression methods, but still unsafe?